# list child page items (1 level with meta keys)

Tags: query-posts

I need to have a index page and it can pull out the title (with link), meta key description and meta key image (meta keys from custom fields) of its child pages, but only one level down.

e.g. I have a index page call WORK, and few child index PRINT, WEB. there will be some pages under PRINT and WEB as well, but I don't want them to be shown on the WORK index. I only need to have PRINT and WEB to be listed and with the meta keys.

Anybody can help please? many thanks!

Comment: Are we talking about menus here?

Answer (score 1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045439/wordpress-retrieving-post-children

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572173/wordpress-showing-custom-data-from-child-pages-pagination

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488628/wordpress-list-pages-with-children

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780148/getting-wordpress-wp-list-pages-to-list-only-relevant-children-hard-as-hell

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160047/wordpress-list-multi-level-parent-pages-when-on-a-3rd-level-child-page

**depth** 
(integer) This parameter controls how many levels in the hierarchy of pages are to be included in the list generated by wp_list_pages. The default value is 0 (display all pages, including all sub-pages).
0 (default) Displays pages at any depth and arranges them hierarchically in nested lists
-1 Displays pages at any depth and arranges them in a single, flat list
1 Displays top-level Pages only
2, 3 … Displays Pages to the given depth

**child_of** 
(integer) Displays the sub-pages of a single Page only; uses the ID for a Page as the value. Note that the child_of parameter will also fetch "grandchildren" of the given ID, not just direct descendants. Defaults to 0 (displays all Pages).

Comment: There's also a `wp_list_pages` filter that you can hook into to pull the meta value you need and display images...